# Unit Test Dispatcher

Tags: unit-testing, botframework

Is it possible to test the Dispatcher with the unit tests? For example I have to dispatch to one of my skill and the should answer with an Adaptive Card which is in the skill. It make sense such a test? Or it should be only in the skill? But I guess that the tests for the Dispatcher would be useful.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to test and in which language? You're not wanting unit tests for [Dispatch CLI](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-tools/tree/master/packages/Dispatch), right? You want it for something like [DispatchBot](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/14.nlp-with-dispatch/Bots/DispatchBot.cs)? Please include the code that you'd like tested and I will help you write a test for it.

Comment: Do you still need help with this?

Comment: HI @mdrichardson-MSFT ... thanks for your reply, actually I was talking about the unit Test for the VA Dispatcher Dialog not the cli (typescript)... and I went deeply in how to use nock with Typescript and meow is clarified. But is interesting how to implement the Dispatcher (LUIS) test through the cli.

Comment: Gotcha. Do you have it figured out, then, or do you still need assistance?